# Django: CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to render each checkbox individually, instead of it having to clump all the checkboxes together in a list, as it does by default? Something like

```
{{ myform.cbmultiple.0 }}
```

To render just the first checkbox? Actually the `0` would have to be a variable so I can loop...

The reason I'm asking is because I want to display these checkboxes in a rather complicated way, so the default widget doesn't work for me. I also don't really want to override the widget because it's much easier to render it using the template syntax than in python code, plus, that's a lot of work for a one-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to render the CheckboxSelectMultiple() manually in the template so you can do what you want with it.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323724/django-i-need-a-custom-checkboxselectmultiple-widget) for details.

The solution could be something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>V</td>
  <td>S</td>
  </tr>
</thead>    
{% for pk, choice in form.options.field.widget.choices %}
<tr>
<td><a href="/link/{{ choice }}">{{ choice }}</a></td>
<td><label for="id_options_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"><input {% for option in app.options.all %}{% if option.pk == pk %}checked="checked"{% endif %}{% endfor %} type="checkbox" id="id_options_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" value="{{ pk }}" name="options" /></label></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}                
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do that because the whole HTML is generated by the [widget's `render` method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py#L466) at once. You could only create your own widget class and override the `render` method so that it produces the HTML in a fashion that suits your purpose!

Comment: That's awful :\ I find Django forms make my life a lot harder, not easier. I think I'll boycott the damn widget and render it myself with straight HTML then nab it off `request.POST` instead.

Comment: Well you're right, though it would be just a few lines of python. It is still horrible that the HTML is inside the widget classes and not using any kind of template!

Comment: Yeah.. it's the (lack of) separation of logic and presentation that I don't like. I want all the view stuff in one place, because I know I'm going to tweak the look a whole bunch more.

Comment: You can at least iterate over the field's choices in the template and present it in the way you want to... Something like `{% for c in form.cbmultiple.field.choices %}Value: {{ c.0 }}, Text: {{ c.1 }} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Might be a good solution. However I didn't find a way to display the input boxes ! Did you ?

Comment: I know this post is old, but someone had found a solution? How to render CheckBoxSelectMultiple individually?

Comment: @Burton449 Maybe checkout [django-floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)....