# Django: Add non_field_error from view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a Django form with a bunch of fields that I'm rendering in the template. I've also got some straight HTML input elements which I want to validate in the view by accessing the `request.POST` vars. If those don't validate, I want to inject an error into the Django form so I can display it on the page. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can also use quite elegant [add_error()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method. Works for Django >= 1.7.

If you set `field` as `None` form will treat the error as "non_field" one.
So:

`form.add_error(None, "I'm non-field error")`

works like a charm.

Answer (score 25):

Adding to Daniel's answer, the specific syntax is:

```
form.errors['__all__'] = form.error_class(["error msg"])
```

Note that you can substitute `'__all__'` with the constant `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` for better compatibility (credit [grafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035824/grafa)).

```
from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can insert anything into the form's `errors` dictionary, and non-field errors go in `errors['__all__']`.

But why are you keeping some fields out of the Django form, only to put their errors back in at the end? Why not put all the fields in the form in the first place? If it's just that you're using a modelform and you want to add fields to it, you can do this in Django by simply declaring the fields at the form level - then you can define clean methods for them within the form.

```
class ExtendedModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field_1 = forms.CharField()
    extra_field_2 = forms.CharField()

    def clean_extra_field_1(self):
        ...etc...
```

Comment: See my other question for reasoning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228722/django-checkboxselectmultiple The field requires a lot of customization that's kind of difficult to do having it in the form.

Comment: @Mark just because you want to customise the display, doesn't mean you can't include the field in the form for the purposes of validation and error display.

Comment: Right.. if I name it properly, Django won't know the difference eh?