# django ModelMultipleChoiceField display in template

Tags: django

```
class AddRoleForm(forms.Form):
     roles=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Role.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

in the template ：

```
{{ form.roles }}
```

the result is like this:

```
 <ul>
    <li><label for="id_roles_0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="roles" id="id_roles_0"> User object</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_roles_1"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="roles" id="id_roles_1"> User object</label></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to show the role's name in each line and get the role's id in the chebox
like:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_roles_0"><input type="checkbox" value="100" name="roles" id="id_roles_0">boss</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_roles_1"><input type="checkbox" value="101" name="roles" id="id_roles_1">employee</label></li>
    </ul>
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

check your model 'Role'

you need add

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Overriding __str__ helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you this post can possibly help you.

Have a look at: [Django - Render CheckboxSelectMultiple() widget individually in template (manually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323724/django-render-checkboxselectmultiple-widget-individually-in-template-manual)

Answer (score 0):

- To change `value` parameter you have to do those steps:

  1. Write your own `CheckboxInput` and overload `render` function. You have to change

     ```
     final_attrs['value'] = force_text(value)
     ```

     to something like that:

     ```
     final_attrs['value'] = force_text(str(int(value) + 99))
     ```

     Other parts can be copied without changes.
  2. Write your own `CheckboxSelectMultiplue` and overload `render` function. You have to change

     ```
     cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
     ```

     to your implementation of `CheckboxInput`.
  3. Use your new widget instead of built-in.

  *NOTE: Parts of code may differs, because they can depends of Django version*
- About issue with `User object`: I'm not sure, but try to check your `__unicode__` function.