# Get ID of a ManyToManyField on ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a particular question envolving the editing of a model with a m2m field that i can't seem to find an answer anywhere. So i have a model, `Equipment` with an m2m relation to `Tests`.

```
models.py:
class Equipment(models.Model):
...
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.manufacturer, self.model)

        pass


forms.py:
class EquipmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        modality = kwargs.pop('modality', None)
        super (EquipmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tests'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['tests'].queryset = Test.objects.filter(modality=modality).order_by('group', 'number')

    class Meta:
        model = Equipment
        fields = ['tests'] 


html:
...
<tbody>
{% for f in form.tests %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ f }}</td>
        <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'app:modal' equipament_id=equipament_id test_id=f.id %}" data-target="#tests">See</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

As you can see i am trying to open a modal for each test field in the form so the user can see some information related to that test. This is where i am having trouble because i cant seem to get that f.id to pass it to a view that renders the modal dialog. Any ideas of how to do that? Please help.

**First Attempt**

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
{% if field.name == "tests" %}
<table>
    {% for choice in field.queryset %}
        <tr>
            <td><input value="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" name="tests" />{{choice.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work because of the queryset. From the documentation it's not supported for a ModelMultipleChoiceField.

**Second Attempt**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for pk, choice in form.tests.field.choices %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ choice }}</td>
        <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'SFM:modal' equipment_id=equipment_id test_id=pk %}" data-target="#tests">Ver</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With this approach i am able to pass pk to the view and load the corresponding modal but i lost my form checkbox. If i manually render it i am not able to save any checkbox. This tells me that it is possible to pass the pk to view but maybe it should be acessible by querying the field form and not only in the choice. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: can you please indent your code properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ModelChoiceField instances in the template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300685/how-to-get-modelchoicefield-instances-in-the-template)

Comment: Sorry @e4c5. Copy paste tricked me.

Comment: @solarissmoke Tried it but it doesn't work for me. That example is for a ForeignKey Relation hence the ModelChoiceField. My case is with a m2m relation. It seems to be the same problem but it doesn´t work here.

Comment: It's the same principle and should work. Please post what you attempted.

Comment: @solarissmoke Updated with what i have tried. That queryset seems to break the rendering of the html code. As i said that example you showed was for a ModelChoiceField although in principle he was trying to do the same thing but it seems that a ModelMultipleChoiceField doesn't support queryset.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323724/django-render-checkboxselectmultiple-widget-individually-in-template-manual) which seems to be doing the same thing as you.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thank you so much. That did the trick. One small thing, if i am not pushing my luck. The form i'm using is for editing a model but it seems that everytime i start the form all the options are unchecked. Do you have any idea why?